# 2D DP with large dimensions

Tags: algorithm, math, matrix, dynamic-programming

Given a n+1-tuple (a<sub>0</sub>, a<sub>1</sub>, ..., a<sub>n</sub>).

We need to calulate F(m, n).

Given:

a<sub>0</sub> <= a<sub>1</sub> <= ... <= a<sub>n</sub>

F(x, y) = a<sub>y</sub> * F(x - 1, y) + F(x, y - 1)

F(0, y) = 1 for all y

F(x, 0) = a<sub>0</sub><sup>x</sup>

I was thinking of dp approach but problem i faced is too large 'm' which can be larger than a billion.

Is there any way to solve this out?

I feel this can be converted to a matrix exponentiation problem but not able to figure out how?

I am new to stack overflow and programming too. Any edit suggestions in question and approach/solution for problem will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Your "matrix exponentiation" idea is correct.

Write `F(x, _)` as a vertical vector.  (That is, one entry for each value of `y`.)

There is a matrix `A` such that `F(x+1, _) = A * F(x, _)`.  Once found, it turns out that `F(x+k, _) = A^k * F(x, _)`.

Now you know `F(0, _)`.  You can find `A`.  Then with repeated squaring you can find `A^m` and now you can answer your question.

Comment: How are you handling the term in addition F(x, y-1). Can you tell the transformation matrix.

Comment: If you arrange your vector vertically with `F(x, 0)` on top, then you should get the upper triangular matrix where the `y`th row is `0` until the diagonal and then `a_y` afterwards.  (Unless I got twisted around somehow, which is not impossible.